# How to get google-cardboard camera FOV?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr

I'm developing an app using Unity3d and the Google Cardboard sdk. I have been trying to get the field of view property for the individual Cardboard cameras. This is working fine in the editor however, when I build it to Android the  camera's fieldOfView property appear to be returning the wrong value.

```
Camera cam = GameObject.FindWithTag("Camera_Left").GetComponent<Camera>();
float fov = cam.fieldOfView;
```

Is this the correct way to access this?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

EDIT

To clarify I don't need to change the FOV. I just need access to a fairly accurate vertical FOV value. I am attempting to calculate the size a game object will appear to the camera using the FOV.

Answer (score 3):

There are many values that determines the `fieldOfView` when using VR. It's just not that `Camera.fieldOfView` property anymore. The StereoController class should be used to obtamin this.

```
StereoController stereoCtrl = GvrViewer.Controller;
Debug.Log("Fov: "+stereoCtrl.matchMonoFOV);
```

There are other variables to look at such as `stereoCtrl.stereoMultiplier` and `stereoCtrl.matchByZoom`.

Comment: Hi, I had a look at this. However unless I'm mistaken matchMonoFOV ranges between 0 and 1 and sets the extent to which the VR cameras matche the FOV of the mono camera..

To clarify I don't need to change the FOV. I just need a fairly accurate vertical FOV value. I am attempting to calculate the size a game object appears to the camera depending on the distance from the camera and the FOV.

Comment: **"To clarify I don't need to change the FOV"** I was not changing anything in my code. `StereoController stereoCtrl = GvrViewer.Controller` will get the current instance `StereoController` so that we can access it's properties with `stereoCtrl.matchMonoFOV`. So, your comment and edit in your question does not make sense.

Comment: You just need to find a way to convert the `0 and 1` to an angle. `matchMonoFOV` is what you are looking for.

Comment: hmm, matchMonoFOV appears to be set to 0 for me.

Comment: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/blob/master/Samples/SpatialAudio/Assets/Cardboard/Scripts/StereoController.cs
.

Comment: Looking at line 88 (in the source code - see above link) it sounded to me like the closer to 1 matchMonoFOV is set, the closer the vr camera FOV is to  the mono camera's field of view.

Comment: That's interesting. Set `matchByZoom` to 1 then try to check if `matchMonoFOV` is now returning a value other than 0.

Comment: matchByZoom sets how matchMonoFOV is achieved - either moving the cameras or adjusting the FOV